# whats wrong with my ajax

Tags: json, ajax, datatables

I need help in my code. if I add "success": function(data) inside my ajax output datatables does not display. My code:

```
    function show_infohouse(kode)
    {
      table = $('#table_id').DataTable({ 
        "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.         
        "searching": false, 
        "orderable": false, 
        "paging": false,
        "destroy" : true,
        "orderable": false,     
        "processing": false, //Feature control the processing indicator.
        "language": {
          "processing": "<span><img src='images/Preloader_3.gif'/></span>"
        }, // you can put text or html here in the language.processing setting.
        "order": [], //Initial no order.  
        // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
        "ajax": {            
          "url": "<?php echo site_url('infohouse/ajax_house')?>/" + kode,          
          "type": "POST",
          "success": function(data)
          {
            var res = eval(data);
            $('[name="grandtotal"]').val(res.grandtotal);
          },
       });
      }
```

If i use "success": function(data) inside my ajax, output display:

```
no  | qty | price  |
====================
1   | 45  | 12.000 |
2   | 65  | 45.000 |
```

but in my code if I remove "success": function(data) my datatables will display data, but grandtotal does not display.

```
output display :

 no  | qty | price  |
 ====================
```

value of grandtotal is 57.000 in the footer of datables, but i need both data items displayed there.

Does any expert know whats wrong with my code?

Comment: the "ajax" option is supposed to be used to load _all_ your data. You're only loading one field with it. https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/

Comment: please help with my code

Comment: I don't know how you currently generate the rest of your table data, it's not shown. But if you use the "ajax" method, then you have to return the table data along with the grandtotal in the same "data" object which is returned to the ajax success method. Read that link I gave you.

Comment: ur link have been read but still dont understand what problem with my code i need expert who help me with my code

Comment: the problem is that you're _not loading all the data_. With the "ajax" you are loading _only the grand total_. You need to assign the rest of the data to the table via the ajax. If you want to do something extra/custom like displaying the grand total, try using the "dataSrc" property rather than "success". That way you're allowed to have the data returned in a different format than the default, which will allow you to have the extra grandTotla property. See here https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax. In particular the example near the text: "Manipulate the data returned from the server"

Comment: Additionally, those docs advise against overriding the "success" callback, as you've done, because you are removing the automatic link between the data and the table. Datatables already implements "success" in the background here, but you have imposed your custom version over the top. All the custom version does is assign one variable, therefore all the rest of the data is ignored.

Comment: ill try using dataSrc is same as success still loading

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to calculate grand total from the sum of all items. Right? So in that case when you remove success you are not getting any response back to the client from server. Success callback is for getting the result from server.

Comment: yes its right so about the data there no problem just case in my ajax where the right place to insert my code so both output grandtotal and result of my datatables can display together